# Show that $ \lim_{s\to\infty} \int_0^1 f(x^s) \, dx$ exists

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. 
How can I show that $ \lim_{s\to\infty} \int_0^1 f(x^s) \, dx$ exists?
It is difficult for me to calculate a limit, as no concrete function or function values are given...

My idea is to use the dominated convergence theorem with $|f(x)| \leq 1$ so that 
$ \lim_{s\to\infty} \int_0^1 f(x^s) \, dx = \int_0^1 \lim_{s\to\infty} f(x^s) \, dx$. But how can I calculate the limit of $f(x^s)$ then? There is no information given about the monotony of the function. Thanks.

Comment: Why is $|f|$ bounded by $1$?

Comment: As $f$ is continuous and $0\leq x\leq 1$, you have that $0\leq x^s\leq 1$ and so $|f(x^s)|\leq\sup_{0\leq u\leq 1}|f(u)|<\infty$. The rest is as you intended: dominated convergence.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the limit, use the fact that $f$ is continuous.
$$ \displaystyle\lim_{s\to\infty} f(x^s) = f\left( \lim_{s\to\infty} x^s\right) = f( \chi_{\{1\}}(x)).$$
In other words, $\displaystyle\lim_{s\to\infty} f(x^s) = f(1)$ when $x=1$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{s\to\infty} f(x^s) = f(0)$ otherwise. Thus the limit of the integral becomes $f(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{s\to\infty} f(x^s)=f(0)$ if $x<1$ and $f(1)$ if $x=1$. Thus, $\lim_{s\to\infty}\int_0^1f(x^s)dx=f(0)$.